# serve.js file inside node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I just came across this script in `package.json` file:

```
"serve": "node ./node_modules/serve/bin/serve.js -p 5050"
```

Upon looking inside that path, I found `serve.js` file and it seemed like the file is used to host and serve the application as the name suggests.

The question is `when` is this file created, or is it created by default?

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "^6.0.2",
"browserify": "^16.2.3",
"canvas-dpi-scaler": "0.0.3",
"chai": "^3.2.0",
"d3": "^3.5.17",
"jStat": "^1.4.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"mocha": "^6.1.3",
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"postcss-cli": "^6.1.2",
"ractive": "^0.7.3",
"ractive-range-slider": "0.1.2",
"serve": "^11.0.0",
"sinon": "^1.15.4",
"sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
"smart-table-scroll": "0.2.0",
"stringify": "^5.2.0"


}
```

And can we open the application in the browser (simply by clicking the `.html` file and loading the `js` scripts referenced in that file) without `npm run serve` and running the `serve.js` file?

Comment: This file is created when you run npm install, i guess that you have a direct dependency to serve.js in your devDependencies section in package.json

Comment: @ElmaCherb yes.. I just noticed `serve` dependency in package.json.
Can we open the application without this serve?

Comment: hard to say, i can say yes if you are sure that you have all your dependencies in your html file. The other problem to solve is Cross-origin CORS.

Answer (score 0):

All of the files inside the node_modules folder are created when `npm install` is run.

If you have already built the project, (probably `npm run build`) then you may be able to run the app like this. Make sure that you are running the output file and be aware that fetch and XHR may not work properly when viewing pages from the file system.